# SQL Server : how to force NOT NULL in a column only if another column in the same table is a specific value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm very new to SQL so any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

I have the following table:

[image]

I need to force NOT NULL on `BusinessName` and `BusinessType`, but only if `CustomerType = 'Business'`. I have already added a constraint on the `CustomerType` column so that only `Business` or `Personal` will be accepted.

If the user wants to set up a personal account, NULL will be accepted in the `BusinessName` and `BusinessType` columns.

Comment: Use a constraint.

Comment: Thanks. Would that look something like this: 

ALTER TABLE dbo.Customers ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name
CHECK Business Type Not Null IF CustomerType = 'Business'

Comment: Just wondering what is the benefit of this conditional rule, just do the validation business logic or in the stored procedure level of inserting customer

Comment: @user123456  It's always better to enforce constraints as close to the DB as you can. You catch all cases that way - there is no guarantee that someone won't use your BL, SP or any other way in. A constraint is very difficult to avoid and as a developer, when you run into a violation you'd be thinking long & hard about what you are trying to do and what downstream assumptions you will be breaking by circumventing it. Much better!

Comment: @LoztInSpace great point I will add it to my programming skills :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a constraint to the exist table like so

```
ALTER TABLE Customers ADD CONSTRAINT Con_First check
(
      CustomerType = 'Business' AND BusinessName IS NOT NULL AND BusinessType IS NOT NULL
      OR CustomerType <> 'Business'  -- BusinessName and BusinessType can be null or not null, we omit AND here
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CHECK (( CustomerType = 'Business' AND  BusinessName  is not null) OR CustomerType <> 'Business' )
```

But your schema could be improved by moving the `BusinessName` etc. out of that table into a business specific one

Comment: I agree fixing the data model would be a better solution.

Comment: @Dan,  if you referring to my comment I have changed its location

Comment: I'm not sure I agree that Business Name needs to be moved out of the table. if it's a one-to-one relationship, there's likely no need, and a `CONSTRAINT` will do just fine. However, for true normalisation, `BusinessType` and `CustomerType` should be in separate "lookup" tables. If, however, Business and Customer have a one-to-many relationship, then a different table is most definitely needed (however, the OP's question doesn't imply this)

Comment: @Larnu The fact there is a `CustomerType` indicates that not every `Customer` is a `Business`.  Pretty much anything is going to give you a better design than this constraint. I'd be looking at tables for each kind of customer. That said, I don't know enough about the problem to be sure.

Comment: That could, however, make for a very difficult query to write if that have other shared items. For example, if all these customers can place orders, and you have 7 different types, that's 7 tables to join on, with conditions on the customer type, not 1.

Comment: The brief states that each customer can be of either Business or Personal type, and that Customers have a one to many relationship with Accounts.

Comment: @Larnu - Our goal is to model accurately the problem domain. "Difficult" is not an excuse when put up against "accuracy" or "correctness". There may be other solutions but I am not a consultant on this problem beyond what is presented here so I make not pretence about giving the perfect solution.

Comment: Difficult (to write, and for the optimiser) is certainly an "excuse" (reason) if it ruins a query's performance. :) If the OP only has 2 Customer Types, then there's going to be little effect here, but I still disagree with the blanket coverage of your comment. And it would scale awfully with the more roles, and respective names, you had.

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks guys - point taken.

So in that case I'd be better off with:

```
CREATE TABLE CustomerID  
(
    Cust_ID,
    CustomerType,
);

CREATE TABLE BusinessCustomers 
(
    BusinessName,
    Address,
    etc.
    Cust_ID **FK**
);

CREATE TABLE PersonalCustomers 
(
    CustName,
    Address,
    etc.
    Cust_ID **FK**
);
```

Comment: Yeah, much better. How are you going to make sure there are no customers that are not business or personal? ;)

Comment: Almost there. 1) add CustomerType to BusinessCustomers and PersonalCustomers, 2) add a PK or unique constraint on CustomerID(Cust_ID, CustomerType), 3) change the foreign keys to composite on both Cust_ID and CustomerType, 4) add a PK or unique constraint on CustomerID(Cust_ID) alone. This will ensure a customer is of a single type and enforce referential integrity.